# "ng-intercom" does not trigger with custom widget and no errors in console

Tags: angular, angular12, intercom, intercom.js

I'm facing the same issue with

- **ng-intercom: v8.0.2**
- **Angular v12.1**

***Code inside Component ngOnInit()***

```
      this.intercom.boot({
      app_id: "alphanumeric_code",
      custom_launcher_selector: "#btnSelector",
        widget: {
            "activator": "#intercom"
        },
      hide_default_launcher: false
    });
```

When the default launcher is true, the intercom appears at the default place.
And when it is made false, the custom widget does not trigger.

Partial **snapshot** of DOM tree with 
[ng-intercom-iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SUSP.png)

***App Module***

```
 IntercomModule.forRoot({
  appId: "alphanumeric_code", 
  updateOnRouterChange: true 
})
```

Comment: Have you had any luck resolving this issue? I ran into something similar the other day.